# Url mapping in Google App Engine Python in multiple files

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url

Is there a way to split the url mappings in multiple files in Google App Engine?

I want something like this:

```
from app1.controller import App1Handler
from app2.controller import App2Handler

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([(r'/app1', App1Handler),(r'/app1', App2Handler)])
```

In App1Handler, I would like to specify some thing like this:

```
(r'/action1', Action1Handler), (r'/action2', Action2Handler)
```

In summary, when user access **/app1/action1**, *Action1Handler* has to be executed.

Django has a similar feature, where admin site urls are included in the main url patterns.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/$', 'polls.views.index'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Is there any such provisions available in GAE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split between the 2 files at the app.yaml level:

```
- url: /app1/.*
  script: file1.py
- url: /app2/.*
  script: file2.py
```

I think you will still need to add /app1 in all your urls in the file1.py files e.g.

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([(r'/app1/myview', Handler),(r'/app1/myotherview', AnotherHandler)])
```

I think this is better because you can use handlers with the same name in the 2 modules, whereas you would get a conflict if you imported 2 handlers with the same name in a main file.

Comment: Thanks user375348. I am aware about redirection in app.yaml, however, wondered whether GAE supports multiple url mappings across files. Anyway, Thanks again for your kind reply.

Answer (score 1):

You could do what @user375348 described by using app.yaml, otherwise you'd need to build your own.  There's an simple router in the webapp2 documentation you can pretty much use straight up.

http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html